# Pytorch's stack() adds dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I am looking to stack one `shape=(1,2)` tensor array on top of another `shape=(1,2)` array, across `dim=1`, using pytorch's `stack()` method.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import torch
>>> np_a = np.array([[1,2]])
>>> np_b = np.array([[3,4]])
>>> print(np_a)
[[1 2]]
>>> print(np_b)
[[3 4]]
>>> t_a = torch.from_numpy(np_a)
>>> t_b = torch.from_numpy(np_b)
>>> print(t_a)
tensor([[1, 2]])
>>> print(t_b)
tensor([[3, 4]])
>>> t_stacked = torch.stack((t_a, t_b), dim=1)
>>> print(t_stacked)
tensor([[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]])
```

The resulting tensor has an added dimension and now has a `shape=(1,2,2)`.  Why doesn't pytorch's `stack()` behave like numpy's `vstack()`?  See below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np_a = np.array([[1,2]])
>>> np_b = np.array([[3,4]])
>>> stacked = np.vstack((np_a, np_b))
>>> print(stacked)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

How do I make pytorch not add a dimension?

Comment: `np.stack` adds a dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you why it was decided to have `pytorch`'s `stack` behave differently from numpy (maybe compatibility with luatorch?). Anyway, to get the desired outcome you can use `torch.cat`:

```
>>> torch.cat((t_a, t_b), dim=0)     
tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
```